# ASP.NET ImageButton with no image

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, imagebutton

I'm Building with ASP.NET a simple HTML based chess game.

My board is a table, each square is a table cell.

If there is a piece on a square, I put an ImageButton within that cell, with the picture of the piece.

The problem is the empty cells. I want them to be clickable (when the user makes a move from A to B, he/she needs to click also on the empty cell B).

I couldn't figure out myself how to make an ImageButton with no image.

Is it possible? Or should I to put a Button control on the empty cells instead? (which is, in my opinion, ugly, since it's inconsistent).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why not create an empty image, a placeholder if you will?  That way it reserves the space, but has no image, and can be reused as needed.

Comment: @DarkBobG thought about it. it seems to me very old fashion... a bit too clumsy for such a simple problem, don't you think?

Comment: why dont you just create the image for empty box, which will just have white/black box, and change the image of field accordingly.

Comment: @RahulR. if anything i would prefer to use some transparent image. if i use a black/white image, i'll need to change it every time i want to change the look of the board.

Comment: @Letterman i think you only came up with good suggestion, just a transparent image would do the trick,

Comment: @RahulR. yes it'll definitely do the trick... i just want to be sure what would be the best way... i think it's weird we need to create transparent images, instead of ImageButton to support no image.

Comment: It's not really weird; sometimes solutions that are simple, are the best solution, whether they really are old solutions to a simple problem, sometimes they are the best.

Comment: just to add to @DarkBobG, image button with no image doesnt make any sense, for that you already have normal button.

Comment: @RahulR. By empty image, I meant transparent.  I apologize if language created difficulty in my suggestion.

Comment: @RahulR. the separation between ImageButton and Button itself doesn't make much sense

Comment: @DarkBobG, it seems my language created problem :), I was only supporting you in my comment :). 
Letterman, you are correct, both are same, its the ASP.NET which has created separate controls for user/developers ease. otherwise with little css you dont have to use image button at all.